# Beispiele von »bedienen« mit positiven Haltungen, Emotionen usw.?

Tags: word-usage, phrase

In den Nachrichten hört man oft Wendungen wie, z.B.

> X bedient (diffuse, ...) Ängste vor ...
>
> X bedient die Ressentiments vieler Menschen.
>
> X bedient das Vorurteil, dass ...
>
> X bedient die Wut der kleinen Leute.
>
> X bedient die fremdenfeindlichen Anhänger der ...
>
> "Die Macher des Films bedienen lediglich die Gewaltlust seitens der Rezipienten." (Aus einer [Magisterarbeit](https://de.scribd.com/doc/52583618/Timo-Maier-Asthetik-der-Gewalt-im-Film-Magisterarbeit-2008).)

In diesen Fällen hat *bedienen* immer ein negativ bewertetes Objekt.

Ich habe nur ein einziges positives Beispiel gefunden:

> Die Fantasyserie »Game of Thrones« ist nicht nur herrlich anzuschauen, sie bedient unsere Lust am Sehen und Verstehen. ([ak](https://www.akweb.de/ak_s/ak582/45.htm))

Gibt es noch andere positive Beispiele als mit *Lust?*

(Die Bedeutung ist hier nicht "jemandem mit Speisen und/oder Getränken versorgen" oder eine andere ganz konkrete Bedeutung.)

Comment: Man beachte, dass auch *Lust* bis heute nicht allgemein als positiv angesehen wird.

Comment: Ich kann deine Argumentation, "bedient" würde ein negativ bewertetes Objekt nach sich ziehen, nicht nachvollziehen - Natürlich ist von außen betrachtet "bedient mein Vorurteil" negativ - Von innen betrachtet, ist die Erfüllung einer Erwartungshaltung aber grundsätzlich erstmal ein positives Ereignis - es war **genau das, was ich hören wollte**. Und wenn mich der Kellner im Biergarten mit einem Weißbier *bedient*, sowieso.

Comment: @tofro Es handelt sich hier nicht um alle Bedeutungnen von "bedienen", sondern um bedienen + Haltungen/Emotionen.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Ich weiss - Trotzdem wurde meine Erwartungshaltung auch bei einem Vorurteil  *positiv befriedigt* - Ob sie prinzipiell so toll war, lasse ich dahingestellt.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ich habe ein Beispiel mit "Gewaltlust" hinzugefügt. Und wie tofro sagt, kann man Vorurteile auch als positiv beurteilen.

Comment: Natürlich kann man auch Bedürfnisse, Erwartungen udgl. bedienen, und das ist bestenfalls neutral, aber nicht negativ besetzt.

Comment: Bedienen allgemein ist keine gute Wahl, würde ich meinen,..

Comment: Das ist lediglich Deine Bewertung. "X bedient die Wut der kleinen Leute." könnte ein Wahlkampfstratege, der genau das tun will, eine positive Bedeutung haben. Mit etwas Phantasie findest Du Settings, in denen das bei den anderen Sätzen ähnlich klappt. Das Wort "bedienen" ist jedenfalls nicht an eine Wertung gebunden.

Answer (score 1):

Bedienen kann durchaus auch positiv verwendet werden. Z.b.

> Unser Produkt bedient die natürliche Neugier der Menschen.

Allerdings würde ich zustimmen, dass die Verwendung in den meisten Fällen negativ ist.

Answer (score 0):

Die stehende Wendung

> Ich bin bedient!

im Sinn von „mir reicht es jetzt“ mag dafür verantwortlich sein.

Ich halte *bedienen* aber für grundsätzlich neutral, es liegt an den Substantiven danach:

- Angst
- Vorurteil
- Ressentiments
- Wut

Es mag sein, dass sich für die positiven Substantive andere Formulierungen aufdrängen: Freude braucht man nicht zu bedienen und fundierte Urteile fordern differenzierteren Zuspruch als Vorurteile.

Andererseits habe ich den Verdacht, dass *bedienen* in den genannten Beispielen ohnehin den Hauptzweck hat, sich um eine konkretere Formulierung herumzumogeln. Man will sich eben nicht festlegen, dass etwas Ängste widerspiegelt, sie bestätigt oder gar verstärkt, sondern möchte im ungefähren *macht irgendetwas mit* stecken bleiben.